# Dual booting gone wrong

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, multi-boot, bootloader

Hi I am a user of Ubuntu but decided toto dual boot with windows. I installed windows on a seperate partition but I was unable to access the ubuntu. to avoid loosing my work I removed the windows but now no bootloader was found. Please I need help

Comment: There are LOTS of dual booting guides. Did you follow one? How, exactly, did you set up the systems?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are not booting in UEFI mode.
In this case, you have installed Windows and replaced GRUB by the Windows bootloader,
so could only boot into Windows.
Then you uninstalled Windows (how?) and were left with a Linux partition
but without a bootloader (or one that insists on booting a non-existent
Windows).

A repair utility for such problems is
[Rescatux & Super Grub2 Disk](https://www.supergrubdisk.org/rescatux/).

Use another computer to download the utility and create its boot CD (or USB).
Documentation is available on the website, including videos.
Boot with it and repair GRUB, ensuring that GRUB knows about your Linux installation.

In the future, one doesn't do partition operations or large installations
without ensuring first very good backups, including, if possible,
a backup image of the entire disk (just in case).